# How to do unequality join in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I wish to use `<` in a `JOIN`, but get the error:

> Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Query:

```
select
  o1.order_number,
  o1.datetime,
  LAST(o2.datetime),

from spree.orders_unique as o1
join spree.orders_unique as o2
  on o1.order_number = o2.order_number
    and o1.datetime < o2.datetime
group by o1.order_number, o1.datetime
```

How will I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can vote/star on this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=39

You need to use `CROSS JOIN` + a `WHERE` clause to run inequality

```
select
  o1.order_number,
  o1.datetime,
  LAST(o2.datetime),

from spree.orders_unique as o1
CROSS JOIN spree.orders_unique as o2
where o1.order_number = o2.order_number
    and o1.datetime < o2.datetime
group by o1.order_number, o1.datetime
```

Note you might want use `CROSS JOIN EACH` if this query runs out of resources

Comment: Thanks, a pity it's so slow and no `EACH`